# Nested navigation -- Stack within Tab or Tab within Stack -- in React Native

Tags: reactjs, routes, nested, expo, native

Stacked navigation is not working properly within tab navigation.

```
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name={routes.Area1} component={Area1Navigator}/>
    <Tab.Screen name={routes.Area2} component={Area2Navigator}/>
    <Tab.Screen name={routes.Area3} component={Area3Navigator}/>
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

```
const Area2Navigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    mode='modal'
    screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: defaultStyles.colors.bgHighlightColor },
      headerTintColor: defaultStyles.colors.black,
      headerBackTitleStyle: { color: defaultStyles.colors.headerBackTitleColor }
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name={routes.Area2} component={Area2Screen} options={{
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerShown: true,
      title: 'My Books'
    }} />
    <Stack.Screen name={routes.AREA2_DETAILS} component={Area2DetailsScreen} options={{
      headerShown: false
    }} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
)
```

The problem that I'm having relates to stack navigation nested within tab navigation through the Expo simulator on an iPhone. For example, Area2 has nested stack navigation. The touch functionality stops working in Area2 if ever I navigate to the third tab and then back to the second tab. This problem does not exist in the Android simulator. Has anyone ever encountered this anomaly? I'm worried that this problem would also occur in the real iPhone version of the app and not just in the simulated version.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Can you add Area3 stack and navigation flow code that you used.

Comment: I reworded the problem to make the issue clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this problem with nested navigation--either stack navigation nested within tab navigation or the reverse--that appears in the Android simulator or (in my case) with the Expo iOS simulator is due to incompatible library references within package.json. As of today, the following collection allows both the Expo/iOS and Android simulators to function properly:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.5",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "^9.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~8.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "yup": "^0.28.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
```